# Relacionamento entre Many to Many Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite, digamos que eu tenha os seguintes Models: **Doador,Doação,Instituição**

eu preciso criar um relacionamento entre as doações e as Instituições **INTERESSADAS** na doação, **N** instituições podem ficar interessadas em **1** ou **N** doações. Então exibir para o doador decidir qual instituição vai ficar com a doação.

Devo criar uma tabela pivot? a minha duvida é esta, se também tenho que criar um model para realizar esse relacionamento...
estou em apuros.. como vocês resolveriam este problema?
Obrigado.

Comment: Kassio, poderia melhorar a descrição, ficou um pouco confuso. Por exemplo, a tabela instituição e doação tem um tipo de relação?

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta André, desculpa na falta de informações; Não tem! mas nas regras de negócios, doadores fazem doações, as instituições podem solicitar elas, e o doador escolhe para quem vai!

Comment: Eu entendi que a instituição vai criar várias formas de doação e que o doador irá lá escolher a que mais lhe interessa, logo uma doação pode está relacionada a vários doadores como um doador a várias doações. Sendo assim a relação entre doador e doação teria de fato que ser um Many to Many, como as regras de normalização indicam, é necessário criar uma tabela pra representar essa relação, colocando os identificadores únicos de cada tabela.

Comment: Mas não precisa você criar uma model para definir o relacionamento N M ou N N, mas sim definir nas models Instituições e doação que o relacionamento entre elas são de N M (muitos para muitos)